# Recyclerview with fixed height wont scroll inside nested scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a `RecyclerView` with a fixed height inside a `NestedScrollView` with a few other layouts inside it. The recycler view won't scroll, but it scrolls fine if I set its height to `wrap_content`.

I cannot make the `RecyclerView` use `wrap_content` because there is an issue with `EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener` that it keeps loading data from the server and pushing it into my `Adapter` even if the user has not scrolled down at all.

Most are suggesting to set nested scrolling to false, but if I disable nested scrolling, the `NestedScrollView` does not allow me to scroll my `RecyclerView`. But if I leave nested scrolling enabled, the scroll view does not scroll unless I start touching from outside the `RecyclerView`.

My layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/scoop_background"
tools:context=".module.scoop.timeline.ScoopTimelineFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="92dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivTimelineBanner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="92dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/banner_placeholder" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="92dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvGroupMembership"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvGroupName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_header"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvGroupMemberCount"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@null"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/divider_normal"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/divider_normal"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_white_24dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayoutTimeline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="4dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cvCreateScoop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/divider_small"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/divider_small"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="@dimen/divider_normal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="32dp"
                            android:layout_height="32dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/svg_nav_create_scoop" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:paddingStart="@dimen/divider_normal"
                            android:text="What's on your mind?"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_content" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="32dp"
                            android:layout_height="32dp"
                            android:padding="@dimen/divider_xsmall"
                            android:src="@drawable/svg_insert_image" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/rv"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:clipToPadding="false"
                        android:overScrollMode="never"
                        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="4dp">

                    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What do I have to modify so that the `RecyclerView` is scrollable, but the whole `NestedScrollView` also scrolls along with it, so that if the user is scrolling back up (swiping from top to bottom), the `RecyclerView` will scroll along with the `NestedScrollView`, which will bring the layouts above `RecyclerView`.

**To visualize:**

The layout I'm trying to achieve is similar to that of facebook's. When you scroll down, the timeline will scroll down, and the search bar with the messenger icon at the top is also scrolled so that it is hidden when scrolling down. When you scroll up, the timeline is being scrolled back up, and showing the search bar again.

Comment: post your code here

Comment: I edited my answer to show my layout code

Comment: The relative layout height is fixed, which I have done via code. So the match_parent on recycler view layout should be ignored.

Comment: we have the same issue. do you have a solution for this now?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to do it differently because I wasn't able to solve it with this method. Instead, I used a `CollapsingToolbar` and put the other layouts inside it, then removing its background so it does not look like a toolbar, and it seamlessly does what I wanted to, just with a different implementation.